# can't connect mysql server on windows server from home computer

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2

I install MySQL Server on a Windows Server from Amazon EC2 with all default config (port 3306 is open).
[image]

I edited Security Group on AWS to open port 3306 like this
[image]

But every time i try to connect MySQL server from my home computer, this error show up
[image]

Any one can show me what i'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First: **Don't do this! You shouldn't have MySQL open to the internet**

To do this anyway, you would also need to create a MySQL user that is allowed to connect from anywhere or at least your home IP address (read the MySQL docs to understand how this works).

This is insecure. Instead, either create a VPN or use something like SSH port forwarding and connect only via this encrypted tunnel (and delete the firewall rule allowing this access).

Comment: Because I need a program to run on my computer to insert data into database. Just for testing purpose and I don't have any important things on the server